# imagecopyresized() returning black thumbnails

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, thumbnails

I posted earlier about another resizing script not working and I got a little farther with this script which does things a little differently.

I got a little farther, only now there is a new problem.  The first three lines of the code successfully place three identical files in the target directory with the file and it's two thumbnail files named accordingly.  I then want to load the thumbnails, which are still full-size, and resize them but the script stops at `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and I can't seem to figure out why because `$src` has a value.

I thought that I could possibly remove that line and replace `$source` with `$src` in my `imagecopyresized()` function, and that gets me even closer.  But it then returns a thumbnail of the target size, **but the thumbnail is black**.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath);
copy($newFilePath, $thumb500);
copy($newFilePath, $thumb200);


function thumbImage($src, $dest, $newheight) {
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($src);

  $newwidth = $width * ($newheight / $height);

  // Load
  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

  // Resize
  imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

  // Output
  imagejpeg($thumb, $dest);
}

thumbImage($thumb500, $thumb500, 500);
thumbImage($thumb200, $thumb200, 200);
```

I feel as if this must be a common issue.  Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Don't know what the thumbnails are for.  But if its just to display user supplied images in smaller format, perhaps use a open source dynamic thumbnail creator such as Timthumb.

Comment: @vinsanity38 I have tried other plug-ins but they all do not work the way I want them to, which is why I have built it myself as minimally as I need it.  But there is an even simpler issue here, I guess.

Comment: OK, if your thumbnail images are being returned black, then it is probably the x and y coordinates you are setting for where to crop.  they are outside the image dimensions, so it returns back a black image

Comment: @vinsanity38 well I don't think that's the case... being that I'm starting at the very beginning of the image with 0,0,0,0 and there is no cropping.  I would have to be using negative values to crop outside of the image in my `imagecopyresized()` wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

For me the supplied code block works if I use a JPEG image as source.

The problem may be that you use a PNG image that uses transparency. As JPEG can not handle transparencies, the transparent background colour will be filled. Maybe that is the problem. If not, please provide a sample image that has the problematic behaviour.

Comment: You are sending a header('Content-type: image/jpeg') in your script. Are you trying to directly output the script URL as the image? That will not work as you 1. print the old and new dimensions and 2. you do not output the image data, use readfile($thumb500) for it. If that does not help, please provide a sample image and give your PHP version. For me it works in PHP 5.5.1

Comment: Maybe this answer is of interest for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026646/phpgd-creating-random-black-thumbnails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026646/phpgd-creating-random-black-thumbnails). Is it possible the image has a .jpg as the ending but does not contain a JPEG image?

Comment: the header line was suggested as a fix in another thread, but I find it to not help nor hurt in this script.  The prints were only to check that the other values are not the issue, I will edit them out of the problem.  I am also positive that it is a `.jpg`, the file's name is "healthy-cheesecake21.jpg".  And tell me more about this `readfile` and how I would go about implementing it in the script.

Comment: I need the full URL of a sample image so I can download it to verify that it works for me and there is no general problem with PHP/GD or the image. The `readfile` method is only required if you try to use the upload script directly in the image-tag. (what was implied by the header-line). If you use the URLs of the thumbnail images you don't need to bother with `readfile`;